# WooCommerce: Change remove coupon link in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I want to change the remove coupon link in the cart. At the moment it's the word Remove in brackets: `[Remove]`.

I found the function `wc_cart_totals_coupon_html` in the `cart-totals.php` template.
And I also found the link inside that function.

```
$coupon_html = $discount_amount_html . ' <a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_coupon', rawurlencode( $coupon->get_code() ), defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ? wc_get_checkout_url() : wc_get_cart_url() ) ) . '" class="woocommerce-remove-coupon" data-coupon="' . esc_attr( $coupon->get_code() ) . '">' . __( '[Remove]', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

I just don't know how to change that link part.

It would be really great if the link would appear in the table cell with the label (`wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon );`) instead the cell with the discount amount. But for now it would really help if I could change the link in a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wc-cart-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php) contains on line [295](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L295)

```php
echo wp_kses( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ), array_replace_recursive( wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ), array( 'a' => array( 'data-coupon' => true ) ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore PHPCompatibility.PHP.NewFunctions.array_replace_recursiveFound
```

---

So to change the link you can use

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ) {
    $coupon_html = $discount_amount_html . '<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">My url</a>';

    return $coupon_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 10, 3 );
```

---

To change the table cell in cart you can edit the [`cart/cart-totals.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/cart/cart-totals.php) file on line [35-38](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/cart/cart-totals.php#L35-L38)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try with static url link as per your need.
2. Create code as per the WooCommerce standard.